# New Issue with OpenLayers Plugin Google Satellite - low res?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, resolution

Recently I've noticed this issue with the OpenLayers plugin Google satellite layer where the imagery is dark and of a lower-resolution than it used to be.

I frequently use this imagery with information layers on top for presentation purposes - and recently noticed that the City of Toronto (Canada) is looking far worse than it did a short while ago.  Does anyone know why this may be?

I've included a screen shot to better highlight my concern (notice that outside of the City the quality is how it used to be).

I am using QGIS Wien 2.8.2.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the Google satellite image was updated and it just happened to not be a sunny day?

Comment: Perhaps, however, the darker image is very noticeably lower-res.  Seems unlikely they would update with worse quality...